# Converting hex string with letters outside A-F

Tags: python, hex

I have a hex string as follows:
`\x00\x00\x00\xa5v\xe6A\x0033\x0033\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`

So I know `\x` means to use hexadecimal, so for characters like `\x00` I know that means a null character. However for `\xa5v` how do I go about converting that? Is it a different format to hex?

Comment: These are two bytes, one with hex a5 and one with the ASCII value of letter v.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals "`\xhh` Character with hex value _hh_  *Unlike in Standard C, exactly two hex digits are required."

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ah I see! So it should be 165v? That doesn't seem to be entirely coherent though...

Comment: Python tries to represent bytes as printable ASCII characters if possible and as `\x..` otherwise (each dot represents a hex digit). Assuming that many data is readable text this makes some sense. The decimal representation of the two bytes is 165, 118

Answer (score 0):

You can convert characters that are not hexadecimal, like "v" letter with the python function ord(). It returns an integer of that unicode character. So make something like this: hex(ord("v")) it returns the hex value of letter "v" in unicode format.